# AddExplosionForce in 2D

Tags: unity, rigidbody

Its a pretty simple question. I have a gun that shoots bullets, to make the game more fun i want the bullets to be used to navigate. For example shooting them below you would make the player jump up. I figured this would be a good use case for Rigidbody.AddExplosionForce, but I'm using a 2D Rigidbody, so how do I do it?

Comment: Have you tried to add a force in the opposite direction of your shooting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there's not a built-in function that does what you want, just add your own:

```cs
public static class PhysicsExtensions {


    public static void AddExplosionForce(
      this Rigidbody2D body, 
      float explosionForce,
      Vector2 explosionPosition,
      float explosionRadius,
      float upwardsModifier = 0f,
      ForceMode2D mode = ForceMode2D.Force) {

        var center = body.transform.TransformPoint(body.centerOfMass);
        var offset = center - explosionPosition;

        // You could make this slightly cheaper
        // by deferring the square root until after
        // the early out if you call this on
        // lots of out-of-range objects.
        float distance = offset.magnitude;

        if (distance >= explosionRadius)
            return;

        offset.y += upwardsModifier;

        var force = offset.normalized;

        // Scale force and attenuate to zero
        // at max radius.
        force *= explosionForce * (1f - distance/explosionRadius);

        body.AddForce(force, mode);
    }
}
```

Add this script to your project, and through the magic of [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods), `Rigidbody2D.AddExplosionForce` is now available, using a syntax analogous to the 3D version.

I don't guarantee that this version gives exactly the same results as the 3D version, but since it's in user code, you can alter it as needed to produce whatever results you want.